# What is the nomenclatural/vernacular name for internal browser pages such as "chrome://chrome-urls" or "about:config"?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm looking for the <s>categorical</s> ontological name for internal browser pages that can be called upon via omni-box/URL bar/intent call/URI protocols.  I'm lacking in knowledge of the basic verbiage to conduct further searches to this regard.

Comment: what specifically are your trying to search for?

Comment: E.g., cross-browser/-platform variances in access methodology, user-configurable settings/flags (mobile in particular), etc.

Comment: hmm maybe your best bet would be to poke around open source browser communities, issue trackers, chat servers etc to ask about that type of stuff? It shouldn't be too hard to find someone who contributes to Chromium or Firefox that knows about how these pages are implemented, even if one of them doesn't show up in this thread.

Comment: Mozilla calls 'em "about config commands & settings", https://www.how2shout.com/tools/mozilla-firefox-about-commands-config-settings-pages.html , not generic. To coin a term, perhaps "internal command and configuration page"??

Answer (score 0):

At the time of initial writing, I couldn't for the life of me find an answer, but subsequently it would seem these are now being addressed as "internal pages" or "internals" for short.